# How can I test a Torch installation?

Tags: torch

I installed Torch 7 on Linux. How can I test the installation?

E.g., with Theano, I would test it running `nosetests theano` in the shell or `import theano; theano.test()` in a Python interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
th -ltorch -e "torch.test()"
th -lnn    -e "nn.test()"
```

https://github.com/torch/distro/blob/master/test.sh#L33-L34